# How to pick n number of elements from n number of arrays with certain ratio?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have m number of arrays. Lets say m is equal to 4.

```
 let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 53];
 let arr2 = [54, 55, 56, ...., 76];
 let arr3 = [77, 78, ...., 84];
 let arr = [85, 86, 87, 88];
```

Here I want to pick n elements from all the arrays. Lets say n is equal to 18.

If I want pick 18 number from 4 arrays with certain percentage based on the array length, What would I do?

Result should be like, [1, 2, 3, ......, 10, 54, ....., 58, 77, 78, 85];

I have to divide 18 into 4 different sizes based on array lengths.

I have total of 88 elements from 4 arrays. I need 18 elements differently.

I have tried following.

```
 let prct = Math.ceil((88 / 100) * arr.length);
 let count = Math.ceil((18 / 100) * prct);
```

I have done the same for all four arrays. But it gives me the total of 16 only.

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array is ordered by the length of the arrays descending.

You could calculate only one floored count for the actual element and take the not used count to the next iteration. At the end take the leftover count for getting the wanted amount of items.

```js
var arrays = [
        Array.from({ length: 53 }, (_, i) => i + 1),
        Array.from({ length: 23 }, (_, i) => i + 54),
        Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, i) => i + 77),
        Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, i) => i + 85)
    ],
    total = arrays.reduce((r, a) => r + a.length, 0),
    wanted = 18,
    parts = arrays.map((a, i, aa) => {
        var count = i + 1 < aa.length
                ? Math.floor(a.length * wanted / total)
                : wanted;
        wanted -= count;
        total -= a.length;
        return count;
    }),
    result = arrays.map((a, i) => a.slice(0, parts[i]));
 
console.log(parts);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It gives total of 19 elements.